# PHP include массив

Tags: php, массивы, include

Дан файл index.php. Даны также файлы 1.php, 2.php, 3.php. Нужно имена этих файлов хранить в массиве. Затем перебирать этот массив циклом и в цикле подключите все эти файлы к странице index.php.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

    $arr = ['1', '2', '3'];

    foreach ($arr as $val) {
        include $val . '.php';
    }

?>
```